# How do I increase the font size of \section?

Tags: sectioning, fontsize

I used the following code to increase the font size of `\section` but failed.

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                               {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                               {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                               {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

But it gave me a lot of errors.

Comment: You need to placed it between `\makeatletter` .. `\makeatother`.

Comment: Did you enclose the redefinition in `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`? See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do.

Comment: It would be helpful if you described what you mean by "a lot of errors". We aren't psychics… Did it fail to compile? Did the log contain lots of errors? What sorts of errors?

Comment: hi now it compiled without any errors but there is no visual increase in font size ?

Comment: That's because `\section`s are `\Large` by default in the standard document classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already said you have to use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` because in Tex `@` ist used as special character for internal commands. If you really want to change the format this way you have to change the defaults. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
    {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{test}
\end{document}
```

It might be easier to use a special package like `titlesec`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
    \section{test}
\end{document}
```

or `sectsty`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\Huge\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    \section{test}
\end{document}
```

Or if you are using `Koma Script` you can eaily do:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\setkomafont{section}{\Huge\bfseries}
\begin{document}
    \section{test}
\end{document}
```

I wouldn't recommand to change the `section` format directly. I would use `Koma-Script` or `titlesec`

Comment: what it the default font size of the command \section?

Comment: default for standard classes is `\Large`